# clearInterval isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have an class to handle Markers from Google Maps API. And this is my class

```
function Marker() {
}


Marker.prototype.marker = null;
Marker.prototype.map = null;
Marker.prototype.icon = null;
Marker.prototype.exec_addListener = false;
Marker.prototype.listenerType = null;
Marker.prototype.exec_refresh = false;
Marker.prototype.latitude = null;
Marker.prototype.longitude = null;
Marker.prototype.webservice = null;
Marker.prototype.refresh_time = 10000;
Marker.prototype.id_interval = null;

Marker.prototype.getPosicaoAtual = function() {
    //Instancia o webservice
    this.webservice = new Webservice();

    //Faz o get dos dados de acordo o ID do veiculo
    var url = URL_VW_LOCAL_VEICULO + "&fields=latitude,longitude";

    var resp = this.webservice.get(url, $.cookie("token"));

    if (resp != null) {
        this.setLatitude(resp[0].latitude);
        this.setLongitude(resp[0].longitude);
    }
};

Marker.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(this.getLatitude(), this.getLongitude()));
};

Marker.prototype.refresh = function() {
    //Atualiza a referncia para a classe
    var m = this;

    this.id_interval = setInterval(function() {
        m.getPosicaoAtual();
        m.draw();
    }, m.getRefreshTime());
};

Marker.prototype.stopRefresh = function(){
    clearInterval(this.id_interval);
};

Marker.prototype.destroyYourSelf = function(){
    console.log("Jesus, i'm dying!");
    this.stopRefresh();
    this.marker.setMap(null);
};

Marker.prototype.init = function() {
    //Seta as opções do marker
    var options = {
        "position": new google.maps.LatLng(this.getLatitude(), this.getLongitude()),
        "map": this.map.getMap()
    };

    //Caso o marker tenha um icone, coloca ele nas opções
    if (this.icon != null && this.icon != undefined) {
        options.icon = this.icon;
    }

    //Instancia um novo objeto do tipo marker
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);

    //Verifica se o addListener é pra ser executado
    if (this.exec_addListener) {
        this.addListener();
    }

    //registra o evento para pegar a posição atual, caso esteja setado para isso
    if (this.exec_refresh) {
        this.refresh();
    }
};
```

When i instance a new marker, i set to exec a function `refresh()`, i save the ID in `id_interval`, but when i call the function `destroyYourSelf()`, and in there i also call the `stopRefresh()` to stop the interval loop.

The function `refresh()` do some XHR calls.

The think is, the loop ins't stopping, 'cause i still see the XHR calls.

So guys, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance that `.init()` gets invoke more than once? If so, it'll call `this.refresh()` again, starting a new interval which overwrites the identifier for the first interval, meaning you can't stop it. For that matter, it could happen via a direct call to `.refresh()` too.

Comment: ...maybe put a test in `refresh()` to see if `this.id_interval` is already set to a value, and `console.log()` the result. If so, you need to decide what should happen in that circumstance.

Comment: the ID is setting right in this.id_interval, and the init() is called once time.

Comment: This is just the definition of `Marker`... where's the rest of the code, where it's actually called? You've got a lot of fields you're obviously overriding with something, but you haven't told us what you're overriding them with.

Comment: Well, you've not provided a working example of the problem. You've just shown code that will work properly if used properly. If used incorrectly, it could fail.